# How can I view currently configured Object Change Notifications (OCNs) for a given GCS Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

How can I view currently configured Object Change Notifications (OCNs) for a given GCS Bucket?

I thought it would be as follows:
`gsutil notification list gs://my-bucket-name`

But then I was surprised by this in `gsutil help notification`:

> LIST   The list sub-command provides a list of notification configs
>   belonging to a   given bucket. The listed name of each notification
>   config can be used with   the delete sub-command to delete that
>   specific notification config.
>
> No object change notifications will be listed. Only Cloud Pub/Sub
>   notification   subscription configs will be listed.

**Notice the last paragraph.**

Answer (score 0):

You should add -o like following example:

```
gsutil notification list -o gs://${BucketName}
```

And this will list Object Change Notifications：

```
Bucket ${BucketName} has the following active Object Change Notifications:
Notification channel 1:
    Channel identifier: xxxxxxxx
    Resource identifier: xxxxxx
    Application URL: url=https://xxxxxx.appspot.com/notify
    Created by:
    Creation time: xxxx
```

Reference: [notification command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification)